# 4DD Architecture in ASP.NET

Tags: entity-framework, dns, domain-driven-design, asp.net-identity

Have you ever heard about 4DD and N tier layer with Entity Framework architecture in ASP.NET?. I've searching and on relationship with 4DD I only found DDD, is that correct?. I've asked to my teacher about 4DD and he told that that is how it's named 4DD.

Comment: Never heard of that. Perhaps if you could explain what it is supposed to be?

Comment: 4DD really? there is no "well-known' architecture with name 4DD.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no 4DD architecture

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean **Distributed Domain Driven Design**. It's not widely used, but there is a tag `[dddd]` for it here on SO.

Apparently it deals with DDD specifically in a distributed system. I have to say I don't see the point why we would need a special term for that...

Comment: @Backs Thanks, apparently that link is not generally reachable. I removed it, but its easy to find the `dddd` tag though the search field.